# jquery fadeTo() while scrolling, fading out when going down but not fading in when going back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to fade out a splash when scrolling down, and fading it in when scrolling back to the top of the page. It seems to work ok when scrolling down, but when I go back, it doesn't fades in. I tryed using fadeIn and FadeOut instead of fadeTo but didn't get a proper behavior

The code is actually pretty simple:

```
var splashTop = $('.splash-container').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ((splashTop - $(window).scrollTop()) < 50) {
        $('.splash-container').stop().fadeTo("slow", 0);
    } else {
        $('.splash-container').stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);
    }

});
```

And here is the jsFiddle example:
 [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdelva/339m0a4s/)

Comment: Try: `if ((splashTop - $(window).scrollTop()) < -50) {...}`

Comment: You want to fade it out when it starts scrolling down (irrespective of how many pixels it scrolls down) and fade in when it starts scrolling up (irrespective of how many pixels it scrolls up)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to check if the `scroll` is at the top or not then you don't need to check the position of the Splash, Try:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('.splash-container').stop().fadeTo("slow", 0);
        console.log('p')
    } else {
        $('.splash-container').stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);
        console.log(box1Top)
    }
});
```

Check the [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/339m0a4s/16/)

---

**Edit**

Now why your code doesn't work? ... Because you are always getting a value less than 50:

```
splashTop = 8 always
-  
$(window).scrollTop() = more than 0
```

Then the result is always negative or `8` as max, you can never have a number more than 8 and your else condition is useless.

Comment: Thanks and thanks for your explanation, now it works as expected!